# OIDC authorization handling if webrequest is POST

Tags: quarkus

We have 2 applications and they are connected via an IFrame integration where application A is constructing a POST request (form submit) to application B. Everything works fine if user is authorized already in application B. In case the user is not authorized in application B.

1. Application A constructs POST request for application B
2. User is redirected to OIDC provider (our case Microsoft)
3. Redirected back to callback url of application B and redirected to previous original page
4. Page is blank as step 3 is not passing the body from step 1. Page is retrieved via GET not POST

I understand that this is how OIDC should work but I have to get it working. What I have tried already is to create RouteFilter with 1000 priority. This is the latest state of my code but body is always null.

Quarkus version: 2.16.12

```
    @Inject
    CurrentVertxRequest request;

    @RouteFilter(1000)
    void myFilter(RoutingContext rc) {
        Buffer body = request.getCurrent().request().body().result();
        rc.response().headersEndHandler(new Handler<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Void event) {
                int statusCode = rc.response().getStatusCode();
                if (statusCode == 401) {
                    rc.redirect("back").result();
                }
                if (rc.request().path().endsWith(LaunchHtml.PATH)) {
                    if (statusCode == 302 || statusCode == 401 || statusCode == 403) {
                        if (result != null) {
                            String key = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                            rc.response().addCookie(new CookieImpl(PREVIOUS_PAYLOAD, key));
                            PAYLOAD_STORE.put(key, body.toString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        rc.next();
    }
```

Comment: I don't think initiating an authorization code flow with a POST request can work as the original POST request body is indeed not retained across the redirects. I believe the SPA should offer an option to authenticate the users with GET first and then offer options involving POST. Your custom solution retaining the payload should work though but it is difficult to comment why you don't see the body properly saved.

Comment: Can you try to use the browser dev tools to check what is going with the cookies which provide the payload keys ? It is probably related to the way the payloads are managed